# Why does git confuse removal with rename/copy?

Tags: git

The status report currently shows the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/29176f171b2cdd21ba6a929799b45358.png))</sub>

However, when I do

`git rm include/oogl/Buffer.hpp`

the following happens:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/6c33678bbe4afa2e3ec2cf4a382b637f.png))</sub>

How do I just make it remove that file and leave the rest alone?

Comment: _So saving text to image is easier as pasting it just how it is?_

Comment: When I asked this question, I didn't know how to copy from the Windows console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Git *is* just removing the file.  Renames are detected heuristically based on the amount of identical content in the two files, but **this information is not stored in the commit.**  When you look up the commit later, Git will again determine heuristically if a rename happened based only on the new and removed files.  So don't worry about it.

(See the Git FAQ, section [Why does git not "track" renames?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F), and in particular this text: *"Git has a rename command `git mv`, but that is just for convenience. The effect is indistinguishable from removing the file and adding another with different name and the same content."*)

Comment: My memory fails me, but I think there is a setting to determine how close the files need to be to be considered a rename.

Comment: @Martinho: I can't find such a setting in the `git config` manpage, although I did find one that affects how many files it will examine for renames.

Comment: 50% is the default limit of how low the resemblance can go before it is not considered a "rename with modifications" anymore, but a "delete-add".

Comment: To follow up, @Martinho/cdhowie: `rename-threshold=<n>` on [`git-merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) and `-M[<n>]` or `--find-renames[=<n>]` on [`git-diff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) allow you to control the similarity threshold for rename detection...