# Git: Renaming files with EGit causes deletion of file history

Tags: git, refactoring, egit

I use Eclipse [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) plugin to work with git repository.
(I even use it for local projects to track changes made by tools.)

However I discovered problem that makes usage for team projects not so good:
When renaming a folder or file, I get to commits 2 items: 
1 to add as new, and 1 to delete.
This way there is no history who & when edited this file, no way to look back at evolution.

This problem is likely not  caused by EGit, but git.
See answer for [Renaming in Git and Mercurial: Accuracy and automaticity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957735/renaming-in-git-and-mercurial-accuracy-and-automaticity)

How to keep history of files when a lot of refactoring and renaming is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does git confuse removal with rename/copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586988/why-does-git-confuse-removal-with-rename-copy)

Comment: I don't know much about Egit, but do you have [rename tracking turned on](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_the_View)?

Comment: I have edited test. I need to keep history of file changes. @jszakmeister There's no option to track only 1 operation. It has no sense.

Comment: @PaulV I'm sorry, but I don't understand your reply.  Judging by the documentation, it appeared that turning on the "track renames" option I linked to above would allow the history view to follow across the add+delete.  Git track renames at all... it deduces that after the fact, but only with the right options turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Git FAQ, section Why does git not "track" renames?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F),

This however does not answer how to keep history when usit EGit in Eclipse.
I need to try

p.s. Link for EGit. // Thanks to  jszakmeister

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_the_View

Comment: +1 From EGit user guide you linked: Preferences > Team > Git > History > Follow Renames

Answer (score 2):

Note that with [EGit 3.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/3.0), Rename detection was added to the file diff viewer in the History view and Commit editor ([bug 335082](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335082)):

[image: rename detection with EGit 3.0]

Comment: While true, it does not allow you to compare across renames.

Answer (score 0):

See git help log, particularly the --follow option.

Don't know how to do this in Egit, though, but if Egit isn't doing what you want, why not use other tools to supplimement the basic functionality?